# force a regular plot object into a Grob for use in grid.arrange

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, gridextra, grob

```
b <- ggplot(cars,aes(x=speed,y=dist))+geom_line()
grid.arrange(
    b,
    plot(cars),
    ncol=1
)
```

gives me the following error

> Error in gList(list(grobs = list(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1, height = 1,  : only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"

Let's assume my second graph has to come out of the `plot` function. How would one convert that output to a `grob`-like object so it plays nicely with `grid.arrange` ?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question earlier?

Comment: Yes but without reproducible code and not well laid out. I've deleted the old one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can try with gridGraphics

```
library(gridGraphics)

grab_grob <- function(){
  grid.echo()
  grid.grab()
}

plot(cars)
g <- grab_grob()
b <- ggplot(cars,aes(x=speed,y=dist))+geom_line()
grid.arrange(
  b,g,
  ncol=1
)
```

or, alternatively, use gridBase.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I ended up redoing the plot method with `ggplot2` because using your method I had sizing issues. I'll validate the nonetheless as it does what it's supposed to.