# Only grobs allowed in gList

Tags: r, plot, gridextra

All -- There are several other questions on this exact topic, but none of them addresses the problem I am facing. Here is a simple snippet of code. Can anyone advise what the issue here is please?

```
> grid.arrange(plot(rnorm(1000)),hist(rnorm(1000)), nrow=2, ncol=1)
Error in gList(list(wrapvp = list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1, height = 1,  :
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
```

Comment: @John Coleman is right, base graphics are not `grobs`. If you really wanted to use `grid.arrange` you could try something like using the `grab_grob` function in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826249/force-a-regular-plot-object-into-a-grob-for-use-in-grid-arrange

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that `plot()` and `hist()` are base graphics but not grid or ggplot graphics, hence they are not grobs ("grob" is a somewhat strange acronym for "grid graphical object"). You could either find equivalent grid plots or use a base graphics approach to stacking plots.

The way you would do the latter:

```
> par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
> plot(rnorm(1000))
> hist(rnorm(1000)) #are you sure you want to make a hist of 1000 *different* random numbers?
> par(mfrow = c(1, 1)) #reset this parameter
```

Output:

[image]

You could also consider using `layout`.  Type `?layout` for details.

Comment: Thank you @John Coleman! The best explanation. And no my intention with using the rnorm was just to illustrate. I have got it working using grid.arrange, but using qplot to draw the histogram. It works a treat now!

Comment: @skafetaur I figured that was only an example. I have actually used fairly similar examples when teaching a stats class (I'm a math teacher by trade) in which the same set of random numbers is displayed in different ways in stacked plots, so your example struck me as slightly odd. I do appreciate R's graphical powers but find the way that it is split into different incompatible packages bewildering at times. Finding a pure grid.arrange solution is probably best, but it is good to know about some of base graphic's way to make matrices of plots.