# Saving plots from R to use with grid.exchange

Tags: r, plot, panel

I would like to make a composite graphic which is 3 panels wide by 8 panels tall.  Inside each of the panel would be a graphic that takes multiple R commands to create, like the 1st 3 graphics might be

```
#1
plot(c(2:20), c(2:20), ylab="", xlab="", axes=FALSE)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(c(1:18, c(1:18), xact="n"), type="l", xlab="", ylab="")

#2
plot(c(2:20), c(2:20), ylab="", xlab="", axes=FALSE)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(c(1:18, c(1:18), xact="n"), type="l", xlab="", ylab="", col=2)

#3
plot(c(2:20), c(2:20), ylab="", xlab="", axes=FALSE, col=3)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(c(1:18, c(1:18), xact="n"), type="l", xlab="", ylab="")
```

and then I want to use a command like this to display those 3 side by side:
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot3)

I don't understand how to save #1, #2, and #3 each to be plot1, plot2 and plot3.  Examples of how to save plots all seem to be based on a single plot command, not multiple commands to make the plot.  The help page says grob but doesn't explain what an acceptable grob might be, or how to make it.  Should I screenshot each of those and save it as a jpeg file?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `par(mfrow = c(8, 3))`. This will draw each plot in a single panel of an 8 x 3 grid. And will only move on to draw the next plot when `plot.new` is (implicitly) called.

```r
par(mfrow = c(8, 3))
par(mar = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)) # Otherwise margins are too large for 24 plots

for(i in 1:24) {
  plot(c(2:20), c(2:20), ylab = "", xlab = "", axes = FALSE, col = 3)
  par(new = TRUE)
  plot(c(1:18), c(1:18), xaxt = "n", type = "l", xlab = "", ylab = "")
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, that's getting close. Thing is I'm trying to add features to an existing plot, so I don't want to move on to the next plot with par(new=TRUE) because I'm using that to plot 2 time series together on same plot but different vertical axes.  I know TWOORD is suppose to do this but I couldn't get it to work so gave up.

Comment: Also, I was just planning to have the graphic as a pdf run over at least 2 pages; the solution may just be one plot per page, it's only going to go into supplemental materials anyway.  Hmmm. Cheers anyway.

Comment: So... i found out that grob = graphical objects, but that doesn't really help.  And I found out that this code works well for saving multi-command plots:        plot(c(2:20), c(2:20), ylab="", xlab="", axes=FALSE)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(c(1:18, c(1:18), xact="n"), type="l", xlab="", ylab="")              
plot1=recordPlot()     but I'm still failing to get grid.arrange() to accept that, grid.arrange() gives me error msg  = "only 'grobs' allowed in "gList" .. without any info how to make an eligible grob even though I have an R object that seems like a grob.            The quest continues.

Comment: correction, grobs are only generated by ggplot, can't make them from plot....  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742815/only-grobs-allowed-in-glist

Comment: @JuliiBrainard grobs are produced by the grid graphics system (which is what ggplot is built upon). The base R graphics system (as in your plot examples) is quite different. My answer here shows how you arrange multiple base R plots on a single page. There are many options for arranging grobs and ggplots, but far less for base R graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Update & solution:

Don't use `grid.arrange()`, don't use `jpeg()`, `recordplot()`, `pdf()` or `ggplot`...

The below code worked by adding features to the original plots. Then it helps (within RStudio) exporting results as high resolution PNG.  I can label the row/columns separately well enough in MS Word.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
#1
plot1=plot(c(2:20), c(2:20), ylab="", xlab="", axes=FALSE)
par(new=TRUE)
plot1= plot1 + plot(c(1:18, c(1:18), xact="n"), type="l", xlab="", ylab="")

#2
plot2 = plot(c(2:20), c(2:20), ylab="", xlab="", axes=FALSE)
par(new=TRUE)
plot2 = plot2 + plot(c(1:18, c(1:18), xact="n"), type="l", xlab="", ylab="", col=2)

#3
plot3 = plot(c(2:20), c(2:20), ylab="", xlab="", axes=FALSE, col=3)
par(new=TRUE)
plot3 = plot3 + plot(c(1:18, c(1:18), xact="n"), type="l", xlab="", ylab="")
```